# MAUI Best method of setting the configuration per environment

Tags: .net-core, maui

So I have a MAUI app with a lifecycle config of the following

1. Dev machine config
2. Dev environment config (early preview)
3. Staging (UAT) config
4. Production (Live) config

Question: How do I configure the app as it switches between stages

How do I know the app is in e.g.

- Android internal testing and the config should point to the dev environment
- Android Open testing and the config should point to the staging environment
- Android Production and the config should point to the Production environment
- IOS internal testing and the config should point to the dev environment
- IOS Open testing and the config should point to the staging environment
- IOS Production and the config should point to the Production environment

Cheers all

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you wouldn't want mixing up the development version of your app with the production one. Fortunately, you can target different environments through multiple project configurations.

For example, you could have *DEV*, *TEST* & *PROD* configurations.
To do this, open your ***.csproj** file and add following snippet:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
...
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configurations>DEV;TEST;PROD</Configurations>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And from there, you can customize the project configuration in your ***.csproj** file for each of the targeted environments, accordingly to your needs:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
...
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DEV' ">
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'TEST' ">
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'PROD' ">
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This can be relatively long and complex, so if you want, you can read a [complete walkthrough example](https://www.mauicestclair.fr/en/posts/tips/multi-environments-project-configuration/) that I made on this to guide you through it.

Comment: How does the app know which of the dev, test, prod to use? i.e. If my app has passed the testing phase and I promote it to production?

Comment: @Kapusch - Hey thanks for the tutorial, I followed it, but HotReload doesn't work. Did you face similar issue? Not sure if I have missed some config somehwere.

Comment: Have just seen the docs, that HotReload is only supported on Debug config, not custom configs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/hot-reload?view=vs-2022

Comment: Hi @SteveParry , the configuration is applied at build time, so you will have to explicit which ones to use somehow. Could you please update your initial post and elaborate a bit more on your use case?